# Manipulating Complex Objects

Tags: javascript

can somebody help me with this code if it has something wrong or not?

```
var myMusic = [ {  "artist": "Billy Joel",
                "title": "Piano Man",
                "release_year": 1973,
                "formats": [ 
                            "CS", 
                            "8T", 
                            "LP" ],
                "gold": true
             },

             [ {  "artist": "Paco de Lucia",
                "title": "Live in America",
                "release_year": 1992,
                "formats" : ["formats": [ 
                            "CS", 
                            "8T", 
                            "LP" ]]


             } ]];
```

Comment: There's not really any (significant) code or manipulation here.

Comment: If you're just looking for a syntax error. Copy it into http://jsonlint.com/ or look at the errors in your developer console. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this part:

```
"formats": 
[
    "formats": 
    [ 
        "CS", 
        "8T", 
        "LP" 
    ]
]
```

Since the outer "formats" is an array, it cannot have a key "formats" and an array value like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off, try this:

```
            {  "artist": "Billy Joel",
                        "title": "Piano Man",
                        "release_year": 1973,
                        "formats": [ 
                                    "CS", 
                                    "8T", 
                                    "LP" ],
                        "gold": true

            },


            {  
                "artist": "Paco de Lucia",
                "title": "Live in America",
                "release_year": 1992,
                "formats" : [  "CS", "8T", "LP" ]


             } 
             ];
```

Answer (score -3):

Hello thank you folks for everything and the answer is here thank you all:

var myMusic = [ {  "artist": "Billy Joel",
                    "title": "Piano Man",
                    "release_year": 1973,
                    "formats": [ 
                                "CS", 
                                "8T", 
                                "LP" ],
                    "gold": true
                 },

```
           {
   "artist": "Paco de lucia", 
   "title": "la fabuloda guitarra de paco de lucia", 
   "release_year": 1967, 
   "formats": [
      "CD", 
      "Cassette", 
      "LP"
    ]
  }

];
```